# How Can i replace div instead of tr and tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can i add the "Div" Instead of 
Tables & tr

I have tried many time with div instead of Table and tr
and failed
Im just about to create invoice calculation

if any one know about this please let me know
thank you

```js
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    // copy customer details to shipping
    $('input.copy-input').on("change keyup paste", function () {
        var thisID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('input#' + thisID + "_ship").val($(this).val());
    });

    // add new product row on invoice
    var cloned = $('#invoice_table tr:last').clone();
    $(".add-row").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        cloned.clone().appendTo('#invoice_table'); 
    });
    
    calculateTotal();
    
    $('#invoice_table').on('change keyup paste', '.calculate', function() {
        updateTotals(this);
        calculateTotal();
    });

 function updateTotals(elem) {
        var tr = $(elem).closest('tr'),
            quantity = $('[name="invoice_product_qty[]"]', tr).val(),
         price = $('[name="invoice_product_price[]"]', tr).val(),
            percent = $('[name="invoice_product_discount[]"]', tr).val(),
         subtotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
        if(percent && $.isNumeric(percent) && percent !== 0){
            subtotal = subtotal - ((parseInt(percent) / 100) * subtotal);
        }
     $('.calculate-sub', tr).val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
 }

 function calculateTotal(){
     
     var grandTotal = 0.0;
     var totalQuantity = 0;
     $('.calculate-sub').each(function(){
         grandTotal += parseFloat($(this).val()) ;
     });
     
     $('.invoice-sub-total').text(parseFloat(grandTotal ).toFixed(2) );  
 }
    
});
});//]]>
```

Comment: You'll probably get a lot more response to your question if you show what the HTML looks like that you want to replace with divs.

Comment: Why would you place a `$(document).ready()` inside a `$(window).load()`.  There is no reason to ever do that.  The `$(window).load()` always comes after the `$(document).ready()`.  Pick one or the other, not both.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking here.

Comment: Sorry 
I have missed that to add the HTML

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    // copy customer details to shipping
    $('input.copy-input').on("change keyup paste", function () {
        var thisID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('input#' + thisID + "_ship").val($(this).val());
    });

    // add new product row on invoice
    var cloned = $('#invoice_table tr:last').clone();
    $(".add-row").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        cloned.clone().appendTo('#invoice_table'); 
    });
    
    calculateTotal();
    
    $('#invoice_table').on('change keyup paste', '.calculate', function() {
        updateTotals(this);
        calculateTotal();
    });

 function updateTotals(elem) {
        var tr = $(elem).closest('tr'),
            quantity = $('[name="invoice_product_qty[]"]', tr).val(),
         price = $('[name="invoice_product_price[]"]', tr).val(),
            percent = $('[name="invoice_product_discount[]"]', tr).val(),
         subtotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
        if(percent && $.isNumeric(percent) && percent !== 0){
            subtotal = subtotal - ((parseInt(percent) / 100) * subtotal);
        }
     $('.calculate-sub', tr).val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
 }

 function calculateTotal(){
     
     var grandTotal = 0.0;
     var totalQuantity = 0;
     $('.calculate-sub').each(function(){
         grandTotal += parseFloat($(this).val()) ;
     });
     
     $('.invoice-sub-total').text(parseFloat(grandTotal ).toFixed(2) );  
 }
    
});
});//]]>
```

```css
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
    padding: 2em 0;
}
.panel-body {
    padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}
}
.float-left {
    float: left !important;
}
.float-right {
    float: right !important;
}
.margin-bottom {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.margin-top {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
/* Form validation */
 #response {
    margin: 0 1em 1em 1em;
}
  </style>
```

```html
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Create invoice</h1>
  <hr>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">

  <table class="table table-bordered" id="invoice_table">

   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <div class=" form-group">
       <select name="invoice_product[]">
        <option>Versa Table - Wildberry</option><option>Versa Table - Aubergine</option><option>Versa Table - Blue Jazz</option><option>Versa Table - Tundra Spring</option>       </select>
      </div>
     </td>
     <td>
      <div class=" form-group form-group-sm">
       <input class="form-control calculate" name="invoice_product_qty[]" value="1" type="text">
      </div>
     </td>
     <td>
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
       <span class="input-group-addon">£</span>
       <input class="form-control calculate" name="invoice_product_price[]" value="0.00" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" type="text">
      </div>
     </td>
     <td>
      <div class=" form-group form-group-sm">
       <input class="form-control calculate" name="invoice_product_discount[]" placeholder="Enter % or value (ex: 10% or 10.50)" type="text">
      </div>
     </td>
     <td><div class=" form-group form-group-sm">
                         <div class="col-lg-2">
    <input type="text" name="sub_total" class="form-control calculate-sub" id="subtotal" value="0.00" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" disabled>
   </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="row text-right">
   <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-8">
    <p>
     <strong>
      Sub Total: <br>
             TAX/VAT: <br>
            Total: <br>
     </strong>
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-2">
     <strong>
      £<span class="invoice-sub-total">20.00</span> <br>
             £<span class="invoice-vat">0.00</span> <br>
            £<span class="invoice-total">0.00</span> <br>
     </strong>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: is that an answer or are you just 'editing' the question in an answer ? if the latter, just edit the question. Also use the twitter-bootstrap tag.